# In Angular2, need sum of the value in text boxes

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular2 app, I have a `*ngFor` loop to show model names coming from JSON. 
The parent template code looks like this

```html
<div *ngFor="#model of datajson.models">
    <models [data]="model"></models>
</div>
```

Now for the child component, the code looks like this

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'models',
    template: `
        {{data.modelname}}
        <input type="text" class="txt-dev-number" [(ngModel)]="devCount"/>
    `,
```

Here in the last line, I have a text box for each model name which will take numbers.
Question is how to get the sum of all the values in the text boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a count property to your model in order to bind the devCount to it.

see the below plunker example:

http://embed.plnkr.co/ct6gdEAGOvblvDZxN0gp/